# How to define DataContext in my Resource File or under Window.Resource tag?

Tags: wpf, resources, datacontext

I have this binding:

```
<Window x:Name="_local">

    <TextBox x:Name="txtVendorName" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=VendorObject}"  Width="200" Height="50" BorderBrush="Black" Text="{Binding Path=VendorName}" />
```

if i have 50 textboxes and label which I need to bind, do I need to put DataContext for all??

Is there a way I can centralize this DataContext and only define Text/Content for my objects?

I don't want to define DatContext to my Grid. So how can I define DataContext in my?

```
<Window.Resources></Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Just found out that we can define DataContext in the Window Tag too. But, I need to find how to define in my separate Resource file?

Comment: you can very well define resource dictionary in separate file and then use Merge dictionary feature to integrate into your main xaml file. You can set DataContext in seprate file. look for some examples on web, it should be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am guessing your actual requirement right, then what you want is all 50 labels and textblocks should be bound to the data context which is `VendorObject` from `_this` object. Although I couldnt really guess what `_this` object is.

Well `DataContext` is an `Inherited Dependency Property (IDP)` what they mean is when a visual parent is set with a data context its data context is acquired by all the children below that visual.

So if you put some `Panel` in your window and set its data context once with your binding `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=VendorObject}"` and then put all those 50-100 textblocks and labels under that panel then they will automatically acquire that vendor-object as the data context.

So

```
  <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=VendorObject}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=VendorName}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=VendorId}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=VendorLocation}" />
      .... <!--Put all the 50 UI items here to use same data context -->
  </StackPanel>
```

I hope I guessed correctly of what you need.

Now answering you next question,

---

> So how can I define DataContext in my?
>
> ```
>   <Window.Resources></Window.Resources>
> ```

---

You cant. But you can create an instance of `VendorObject` class and give it a resource `Key`, but thats simply a bad design.

Comment: Thanks a lot AngelWPF. That really helped me a lot and also cleared my lot of uncleared question.